# What happens to Numpy/Scipy pointers when they are copied to local variable?

Tags: python, pointers, numpy, scipy

I am aware that numpy arrays are pointer arrays.  And I know that is possible to define pointers in python.  But I am wondering, if I make a variable equal to an element in a numpy vector, is it still a pointer or is it de-referenced?  Is there a way I can find out or test this?

Example

```
    import scipy
    vec = scipy.randn(10)
    vecptr = vec # vecptr is a pointer to vec
    vecval = scipy.copy(vec) # vecval is not a pointer.

    var = vec[3] # is var pointer or is it copied by value ???

    print(type(var)) # returns numpy.float64.  does this mean its a 1x1 numpy vec and therefore  a pointer ?
```

The reason I ask is, what I really want to know is; will the code below this double up my memory?  I am trying to create more meaningful variable names to my vector that is returned

```
    v = self.viewCoefs[sz][sv][sa]

    gw = v[0]
    G0 = v[1]
    G1 = v[2]
    G2 = v[3]
    alpha0 = v[4]
    alpha1 = v[5]
    alpha2 = v[6]
    beta0 = v[7]
    beta1 = v[8]
    beta2 = v[9]
    beta3 = v[10]
    gamma0 = v[11]
    gamma1 = v[12]
    gamma2 = v[12]
    gamma3 = v[12]
    gamma4 = v[13]
    delta0 = v[14]
    delta1 = v[15]
    delta2 = v[16]
    delta3 = v[17]
    delta4 = v[18]
    delta5 = v[19]
    zeta_prime_0 = v[20]
    zeta_prime_1 = v[21]
    zeta_prime_2 = v[22]
    Gamma_prime_0 = v[23]
    Gamma_prime_1 = v[24]
    Gamma_prime_2 = v[25]
    Gamma_prime_3 = v[26]
```

Because I have lots of these to follow

```
    p0 = alpha0 + alpha1*scipy.log(bfrac) + alpha2*scipy.log(bfrac)**2
    p1 = beta0 + beta1*scipy.log(bfrac) + beta2*scipy.log(bfrac)**2 + beta3*scipy.log(bfrac)**3
    p2 = gamma0 + gamma1*scipy.log(bfrac) + gamma2*scipy.log(bfrac)**2 + gamma3*scipy.log(bfrac)**3 + gamma4*scipy.log(bfrac)**4
    p3 = delta0 + delta1*scipy.log(bfrac) + delta2*scipy.log(bfrac)**2 + delta3*scipy.log(bfrac)**3 + delta4*scipy.log(bfrac)**4 + delta5*scipy.log(bfrac)**5

    subSurfRrs = g*(p0*u + p1*u**2 + p2*u**3 + p3*u**4)
    ## and lots more
```

So I would like meaningful variable names without doubling my memory foot print.

#

Okay, If I got it right, the solution to NOT double up my memory is :

```
    v = self.veiwCoefs[sz][sv][sa]

    gw = v[0:1]
    G0 = v[1:2]
    G1 = v[2:1]
    alpha0 = v[3:4]
    alpha1 = v[4:5]
    alpha2 = v[5:6]
    beta0 = v[6:7]
    beta1 = v[7:8]
    beta2 = v[8:9]
    beta3 = v[9:10]
    ## etc 

    p0 = alpha0[0] + alpha1*scipy.log(bfrac) + alpha2[0]*scipy.log(bfrac)**2
    p1 = beta0[0] + beta1[0]*scipy.log(bfrac) + beta2[0]*scipy.log(bfrac)**2 + beta3[0]*scipy.log(bfrac)**3

    ## etc
```

Comment: You really don't need to worry about "doubling up" memory usage in this case.  It's just 27 floats. If 216 _bytes_ of memory usage matters to you, don't use python...  That having been said, there are cases where a single-element view of a numpy array is useful, but this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost have it, but here is how to create a view of a single element:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [23]: v = np.arange(10)

In [24]: a = v[3:4]

In [25]: a[0] = 100

In [26]: v
Out[26]: array([  0,   1,   2, 100,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9])
```

Here `a` is a view of the fourth element of `v`, so when you change `a` you change the corresponding position in `v`.

Comment: So is it fair to say that if I do :  gw = v[0]
        G0 = v[1]
        G1 = v[2]
        G2 = v[3]
        alpha0 = v[4]
        alpha1 = v[5]
        alpha2 = v[6]  and so on.    I am not doubling up my memory usage?  I am just creating more useful handles for my vector?

Comment: @Caustic - `gw = v[0]` would make a copy of the element, while `gw = v[0:1]` would create a view which is not a copy, but more like an alternative label for that place in memory.

Comment: Okay I think I got it now.  I need to use gw[0], G0[0], .. etc.  with the square brackets.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Views are very useful, and using them well can help save quite a bit of memory, but in your case I don't think views are appropriate. While a view does reuse the underlying data, I would not call it a pointer. Each view is a unique ndarray object, meaning it has it's own properties, for example shape:

```
In [4]: a = np.arange(7)

In [5]: b = a[1:5]

In [6]: b.shape = (2,2)

In [7]: b
Out[7]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
In [8]: a.shape
Out[8]: (7,)
```

so when you do `b = a[0:1]`, you're creating a brand new ndarray object to hold one int/float/... or whatever. If you want you have meaningful names for each element of your array, you're probably not going to get much more efficient than:

```
v = self.viewCoefs[sz][sv][sa]

gw = v[0]
G0 = v[1]
G1 = v[2]
G2 = v[3]
alpha0 = v[4]
## etc
```

That being said, you should try and see if there is a better way to vectorized you code, meaning try to write your code as operations on arrays instead of operations on elements of arrays. For example you might write:

```
coefs = np.zeros((5,5))
lt = np.tril_indices(5)
coefs[lt] = self.viewCoefs[sz][sv][sa]

p = (coefs * scipy.log(bfrac)**[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).sum(-1)
subSurfRrs = g*(p*u**[1, 2, 3, 4]).sum()
```

Vectorized code can be much faster when using numpy. In this case we also exploit numpy's broadcasting, which I thought was very confusing until I got to know it a little better and realized how useful it could be.

Comment: Thanks @Bago, Vectorized code is the way to go.  after I have convinced my self all of the coefficients are correct.  It is the way I am used to doing things in Matlab.  Keeping the terms seperate for now is more useful for debugging.